# Checking sync state of client and server when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization, client-server

I have a web application with a big order form: 300+ input fields for item amounts, each with a button to increase and decrease the amount. Each change in an input field is sent to the server via Ajax. The buttons are "debounced": Clicks are collected and the new amount is sent 200 ms after the last click. Now it seems that some requests fail, probably due to bad network conditions, but it could also be a server problem. This means that the displayed amount and the the amount stored on the server differ. **What strategies can I use to keep client and server in sync**? At the moment I see two options:

- Error handling on the client - when a request fails, re-send it (with a maximum number of tries).
- Calculate a checksum/hash of all amounts and send it together with the amount. If the server calculates a different amount, it returns an error code and all field contents are sent to the server.

Any other ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a ChangeLog (a list of ids of records that are to be synced with the server) on the client side (just ids, not the record itself).

Then during a sync process make sure the server sends back an acknowledgement of having successfully processed a record.

If success, remove the record from the ChangeLog. If not, it stays and will be re-sent during the next sync process.

This is the protocol used by SyncML standard and may apply to your case.